# Given 2 sorted arrays. Need to find one number in each, so that their sum is closest to a predetermined number

Tags: arrays, algorithm

Given two increasingly sorted arrays (with lengths p and q respectively). Need to find one element of each array, so that their sum is closest to a predetermined number. Complexity should be O(p+m).

Comment: This has been closed anyways but StackOverflow active posters are asked not to answer questions that show no **efforts** for trying to solve their own problem, I think you should try it for your next questions with actual attempts at solving this, and many of us will be pleased to help you.

Comment: Well, at least enough research effort to avoid duplicate questions that people post again and again.

Comment: @aduch And how I can show my efforts? Show my wrong solution and ask why it's not working or how to make it more efficient? As far as I know people don't like to find mistakes in other's people solutions and such questions will be down voted.

Comment: @Alexander Oh I see where you're going, and you are right. Sometimes people are downvoting as soon as there are too many errors in the code, and it might be right. But I think that if you are being honest with the fact that you know there are errors, it sounds different. As David stated above, showing that you did some research if you didn't come up with a draft after all, will probably hurt you less from your questionning. Always search for a similar question that could already have been asked before asking it.